# Why does form_for class addition only work when i explicitly declare a submit label?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I am trying to style form elements within this rails form_for but continually run into syntax error, nothing i try seems to be working:

**_form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(@todo_list) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <%= f.submit, html: {class: "btn btn-default btn-xs"} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

This just gives this error:

> _form.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '=' ...buffer.append=( f.submit, html: {class: "btn btn-default btn... ...

All sorts of variations of `class=`, `class:`, `html=>`, passing in `html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}`, etc etc, all just seem to give the same syntax error.

The only exception is when I explicitly apply a label to the submit action, e.g.;

```
<%= f.submit 'Save', class: "btn btn-default btn-xs" %>
```

Then the class gets added successfully and my bootstrap styling works. However this neither locates the primary problem nor solves it as then I can't use rails' form_for dynamic naming of the submit action.

Classes I apply to divs seem to work fine, bootstrap is loaded fine. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: The issue was that i wasn including a comma where i shouldn't have been;

`<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %>`

not

`<%= f.submit, class: "btn btn-primary btn-xs" %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because `submit` is a function and the first argument is the label. You cannot write `f.submit,` as you did in your code example.

You need to supply at least `nil` as a label if you're wanting to add the second argument. The correct way to do this would be:

```
<%= f.submit nil, html: {class: "btn btn-default btn-xs"} %>
```

From [APIDock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/submit)

> submit(value=nil, options={}) public

Comment: Because the default label is `nil`, just look at the definition. When you write `f.submit` by itself, it's the same as writing `f.submit nil, {}`

Comment: Thanks Wes, appreciated.

Comment: 2018 update on rails 5 and ruby 2.4.  <%= f.submit nil, class: "btn btn-primary" %> worked for me, the accepted answer above did not.